# Variation of Morse Functions: a reference request

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry, morse-theory

Suppose I have a manifold $X$ and a family of Morse functions $F_t:X \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ on it where $t$ is the second parameter. So, if we fix $t$, we get a regular Morse function for most values of $t$, but not all.

I want to understand how the Morse structure (the associated cell complex and the signature of the quadratic form at singular points) can change as we vary $t$ through these points where the function stops being morse. What is a reference to literature on this?

In my setting, $X$ is really defined by a set of polynomial equations (satisfying some symmetries) so perhaps we should really think of variation in the sense of monodromy with $t$ being a complex parameter.

Comment: @John Klein wrote some papers about the space of Morse functions. Not sure if you will find answer to your specific question, but that may be relevant.

Comment: Do you have an example where the signature of the quadratic form (at a possibly-time-varying critical point) varies along your family of Morse functions?  I would have expected that somewhere in the Cerf theory literature tells you that most of your Morse data (possibly even isomorphism type - not just chain homotopy type - of the Morse chain complex) is constant on connected components of the space of Morse functions; obviously the data can change at birth-death singularities but at these times the function is not Morse.  The Morse cell complex seems somewhat more difficult to reason about.

Comment: I think I didn't make it clear but I don't think the function is Morse at all points of t. The examples I have in mind are primarily when the number of critical points goes down. A one dimensional example would be something like $x^2 - t$. I edited the question to make this clearer

Comment: The keyword is cerf theory. Generically you can understand the singularities of the homotopy. There are models for this. For the morse complex: i vaguely recall a paper by cornea and someone on this

Comment: Thanks, Cerf theory is exactly what I am looking for! @thomasrot